# change install path to windows install directory?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I am trying to change the installation path of my app in wix, by changing

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="WINDOWSVOLUME">
    <Directory Id="SUB_FOLDER" Name="Engage">
      <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="EngageSetupCreator" />
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
</Directory>
```

Here I expect to create a directory("Engage") inside C drive which is my windows installation drive and install my app inside it.

But currently it work like, if I run the installer from d drive it will create a folder In D drive.

How to fix this?

Comment: I would like to caution this approach as it is not guaranteed that there exists a C:\ on the machine you are installing on.

Comment: then give me a proper solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your drive will be selected by the free space or some other criteria.

You can overwrite this selection be defining the RootDrive.

`<Property Id="ROOTDRIVE" Value="C:\"/>`

Comment: THANK YOU, PLEASE UPVOTE MY QUESTION